# Question Regarding how to handle token refreshes for AWS Python Lambdas Integrations and Google API

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-api

I'm new to Google APIs so My question deals with creating an AWS lambda python integration that will call Google Campaign Manager 360 DFA Reporting scope. It will take the report data and place it in an S3 bucket for SA analysts to run BI and Qlik reports (So far, the data pull works with Postman which I use for testing but its web-based).  My  Lambda code runs in AWS  - in the background and I am using OAuth2.0 for my Google project and for Postman web app.

My questions are:

Q) How do I handle token refreshes for a background AWS python integration? Are there any good examples that I could look at?
Q) If integration sign-on needs to be used, how difficult or time consuming would that be?
Q) Can I simply use Rest API and the bearer token to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: I'm thinking that Google Service Accounts should be the way to go  according to the 2nd bullet point here: https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Cloud-Hub/Access-token-expiration-time/m-p/529757#:~:text=Set%20a%20Longer%20Expiration%20Time,expires_in%22%20parameter%20when%20you%20authenticate.

Answer (score 0):

Since I am dealing with Servcer-to-Server interactions then it would be best to use Google Service Account. Please See:
[https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Cloud-Hub/Access-token-expiration-time/m-p/529757#:~:text=Set%20a%20Longer%20Expiration%20Time,expires_in%22%20parameter%20when%20you%20authenticate](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Cloud-Hub/Access-token-expiration-time/m-p/529757#:%7E:text=Set%20a%20Longer%20Expiration%20Time,expires_in%22%20parameter%20when%20you%20authenticate).